# Is it possible to make a router with 4G out of a sim card, and how?

Tags: router, mobile-phone

I bought a sim card from an mobile provider, and I can use it as a hotspot, using my cellphone. So, I can make my cellphone into a hotspot router, using this sim card. Do you have some recommendations on which router (a proper piece of hardware, not a cellphone) would work with 4G sim card, as a hotspot router? The 4G+ is written on the provider's site, if I find more info on bands I will have them written here.

Comment: Do you have any idea the bands your SIM operator operates on?

Comment: In regards to bands, 4G+ is written. If I find something else, I will update the question more.

Comment: Why do you want a separate piece of hardware as opposed to just using your phone?

Comment: @JMY1000 because I do! :) Haha, well, because it gets really hot, and I only love myself and my best girl to be hot :) not a stupid iPhone..... ;)

Comment: Getting hot isn't really an issue most of the time, I'd strongly recommend just using your phone.

Comment: @JMY1000 exactly my point! ;) AHAHA

Comment: It really does get hot, and I love my phone!!!! I don't want to ruin it by using it as a router!!!

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic Where is the 4G+ found? On your phone's notification shade? Because some phone's OS s actually just show 4G+ for Higher frequency bands instead of carrier aggregation. Can you please tell me your operator and the city you live in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you're looking for something like one of the following:

1) **TP-Link M7350 Mobile Router**

2) **Huawei E5577**

***Bonus:*** If you're not on a tight budget here's one of my favorites
the **Netgear AC810-100**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, even though, the first one costs around 100 euros, right?

Comment: It all depends on country and stores.. For Example: in the Italian Amazon Store, the TP-Link costs around 79,99€ - in the English site (.co.uk) it goes from 74,49£ to 79,99£ (that converted in €s it’s 89€ ~). From my experience, Huawei tents to keep the price a little bit lower than other vendors, but most of the phone carriers use the Huawei network chip for their “branded” 4G router, so even tho you’d cheap out a little, you won’t sacrifice quality. Obviously those 3 are not the only 4G routers out there, so if you find one that better fits your need, feel free to go for it :)